# Get the power status of a connected TV on linux

Tags: linux, status, television, hdmi

I'm currently trying to turn my display off and on when I leave / enter the house.

I'm running an Ubuntu HTPC which is connected to a Samsung TV by HDMI (Intel HD4600).
Using 'xset dmesq ...' results in switching the HDMI output off/on and doesn't change the power status of the TV (it just looses the signal). Therefore I connected an IR transmitter which is able to turn the tv off or on -  sadly both commands are using the same IR code, resulting in the power status to tip over.

The xset status also doesn't return the right status, it's always seen as "On", regardless of the power status:

```
<hashworks:~> DISPLAY=:0 xset q | grep 'Monitor is'
Monitor is On
```

I could save the last display status, but this will result in wrong values when I turn the TV off using the remote etc. The IR transmitter isn't getting anything back as well.

Is there any other way to check the current status?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is CEC.

This thread ("Turn on / off TV via HDMI CEC") appears informative:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=15749

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the HD4600 of the i5 Haswell Processor, which doesn't support CEC.